# References for this function: $\Psi_{\chi}(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n){e^{-n^s}}?$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, analytic-continuation, l-functions

Consider $$\Psi_{\chi}(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n){e^{-n^s}}$$

where $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character.

> Is anything known about it?

I looked around and didn't see any references involving this function.

> Are there any references to read about this function? Any online videos?

I'll take references at any level.

Comment: No, it hasn't been studied. It's not interesting from the point of view of analytic number theory. The whole point of the Dirichlet series $L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \chi(n) n^{-s}$ is that it is the generating function associated to a multiplicative function; in particular, the coefficients $f(n) = \chi(n) n^{-s}$ of this series are completely multiplicative, so that $f(mn) = f(m) f(n)$. This isn't the case for $f(n) = \chi(n) e^{-n^s}$, so I can't imagine there would be any reason to study this.

Comment: As Peter said, this has almost certainly not been studied. I'll add that if you squint, you might mistake this for a twisted theta function $\theta_\chi(z) = \sum \chi(n) e^{2 \pi i n^2 z}$.

Comment: @davidlowryduda thanks for your comment

Comment: @PeterHumphries thanks for your comment

Comment: Can I ask about $\sum e^{-\chi(n)-n^s}$?

Comment: It's not interesting either. Why are you asking these questions? Are you trying to generalise $L$-functions for the sake of generalisation?

Comment: @PeterHumphries my professor told me that $\varphi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^s}$ and it's continuation to complex plane is involved in a general theory and recommended that I read about elliptic functions to start getting into this theory

Comment: I don't see any major connection to elliptic functions.

Comment: Yeah I was also confused as to why he said that...maybe he is not telling me correct info